# Custom modal - how to stop a save buttons default behavior so the custom modal can do its thing first?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Av Asp.Net MVC web app.

I am using the Window.confirm() method to display the modal dialog when a save button is clicked. It works fine - the modal appears and waits for a response before executing the controller code.

However, I want a better looking modal.

How do I get it to block the controller code execution and 1st wait for my modal to respond? I'm told the modal is not a true modal and that I need a handler in there. Just not sure how or where to code that.

The Razor view (simplified - not showing fields):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessSaveUserProfile", "UserProfile", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              .....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary saveButton"; />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.ActionLink("Cancel Changes", "GetUserProfile", "UserProfile", null, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

@* Modal. *@
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal4" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body" style="padding:10px;">
            <h4 class="text-center">Are you sure you want to save. Continue ?</h4>
            <div class="text-center">
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-yes4">Yes</a>
                <a class="btn btn-default btn-no4">No</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".saveButton").click(function (e) {
        // Trigger(show) the modal.
        $("#myModal4").modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
        });

        // Pass true in the callback function.
        $(".btn-yes4").click(function () {
            $("#myModal4").modal("hide");
            return true;
        });

        // Pass false in the callback function.
        $(".btn-no4").click(function () {
            $("#myModal4").modal("hide");
            return false;
        });

        // Remove the modal once it is closed.
        $("#myModal4").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $("#myModal4").remove();
        });
    });

    // The standard Window.confirm() method. It works - blocks the controller code execution and waits 
    // for a response. But it is ugly.

    //$('.saveButton').click(function (e) {
    //    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to save. Continue ?")) {
    //        return true;
    //    }

    //    return false;
    //});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done!

Give your form an unique Id

submit it on yes button click event.

continue to return false in the submit button.

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessSaveUserProfile", "UserProfile",
     FormMethod.Post, new{id="uniqueId"}))
     {
```

And

```
   $(".btn-yes4").click(function () {
        $("#myModal4").modal("hide");
         jQuery("#uniqueId").submit();
        // return true;
    });
```

And finally

```
    return false;
    });
```

Complete code

The Razor view (simplified - not showing fields):

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessSaveUserProfile", "UserProfile", 
     FormMethod.Post, new{id="uniqueId"}))
    {
       <div class="panel-body">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
               .....
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>

  <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" 
             class="btn btn-primary saveButton"; />
             </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel Changes", "GetUserProfile", 
               "UserProfile", null, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>

       @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    }

   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

@* Modal. *@

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal4" role="dialog">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" style="padding:10px;">
                <h4 class="text-center">Are you sure you want to save. Continue ?</h4>
                <div class="text-center">
                   <a class="btn btn-info btn-yes4">Yes</a>
                  <a class="btn btn-default btn-no4">No</a>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    </div>

     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
         $(".saveButton").click(function (e) {
              // Trigger(show) the modal.
             $("#myModal4").modal({
                  backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: false
           });

    // Pass true in the callback function.
    $(".btn-yes4").click(function () {
        $("#myModal4").modal("hide");
        //return true;
          jQuery("#uniqueId").submit();
    });

    // Pass false in the callback function.
    $(".btn-no4").click(function () {
        $("#myModal4").modal("hide");
        //return false;

    });

    // Remove the modal once it is closed.
    $("#myModal4").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $("#myModal4").remove();
    });
     return false;
});
 </script>
```

**EDITS**:

In order not to bind event click everytime, you can also use this code

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
         var $modal = $("#myModal4").modal({
                  backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: false
           });
    // Pass true in the callback function.
    $(".btn-yes4").click(function () {
        $("#myModal4").modal("hide");
        //return true;
          jQuery("#uniqueId").submit();
    });

    // Pass false in the callback function.
    $(".btn-no4").click(function () {
        $("#myModal4").modal("hide");
        //return false;            
    });

     $(".saveButton").click(function (e) {
              // Trigger(show) the modal.
              $modal.model('show');

     return false;
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Almost...my custom modal appears.1st use case: If I click Yes, it goes to the controller. 2nd use case: If I click No, it stays on the view as expected. However if I now subsequently click Yes, it stays on view. It does not go to the controller. I think setting it to false at the very end shuts the click down for any subsequent clicks..

Comment: I had to warn you about bad behaviour but I forgot... I suggest you use one instance of modal that you'll show and hide. Instead of binding the click event every time. See my last update

Comment: Using the new code and because of the $modal definition, the modal appears immediately. I think I need a 'hide' attribute after "keyboard: false". But I looked for an attribute in Intellisense [like a visible: false] yet I don' think there is one or I don't know which to use. (Provided I am correct).

Comment: I added $modal: hide there and of course it does not appear now at all. so I get no prompt to chose yer or no.